# Reverse the data of column of table without using reverse function,but using loops in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `agent` and it has columns like

```
firstname, middlename, lastname, fullname
```

I want to reverse the data of column fullname with the help of loop in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Use the `reverse()` function.  That is what it is there for.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "reverse the data" ? Do you want to turn "John Doe" into "eoD nhoJ" - or do you mean reverse the order of first and last name, e.g. convert "John Doe" into "Doe, John" or something like that??

Answer (score 0):

Not using `REVERSE` seems like a terrible idea... Consider what you would have to do for reversing [combined characters in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).

Eg ў is a combined character of y and  ̆

In Unicode this is written as first writing y followed by `U+0306` (the unicode for the breve symbol). If you wish to reverse this you would have to take special care for these combined characters by not reversing the order for these special symbols. Otherwise your symbol would appear on another character (or standalone if it appears on the last character in your string).